# jQuery does not send request, but still receives success

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, jquery-select2, x-editable

I am using [select2](https://select2.github.io/) and [x-editable](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/)  libs.

I want to select some tags at select2 box, and send a request to django.
The thing is that script does not send any request (nothing is in console), but somehow thinks, that success message is recieved.

```
views.py:
def lookup(request):
    print request
    c = {'request': request}

    response = render_to_response('res_candidates.html', c)
    return response




script:

$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend : function(xhr, settings) {
        console.log(xhr);
    }
  });


$('.search-jobs').editable({
    url: '/lookup/',
    name: 'jobs',
    mode: 'popup',
    select2: {
        tags: ['C++dev', 'researcher', 'candidate', 'trainee'],
        tokenSeparators: [",", " "]
          },

    success: function(data, config) {
             alert(data);

    },
});
```

Comment: You should try and reproduce with jsfiddle. It's hard to see what is going on here.

Comment: If you're using Select2 4.0.0, I would recommend using the [recently forked version of x-editable](https://github.com/select2/x-editable) that is compatible with it.